# In the expression $a+it$ for a complex number, is the "$+$" just there to join the real and imaginary parts? or do the rules of arithmetic apply?

Tags: complex-analysis

We know a complex number is given as:
$$a + it \quad\text{where}\quad i= \sqrt {-1} $$

"$a$" and "$t$" are both real numbers, and "$i$" is an imaginary unit. (Complex numbers can be defined as ordered pairs $(x, y)$ of real numbers that are to be interpreted as points in the complex plane.)

> What does the *addition sign* ("$+$") have to do with this expression?

Was the addition sign put just to keep these so-called "real" and "imaginary" parts together, as in vectors? Are the rules of arithmetics really applicable here? For example,

- multiplication of two complex numbers
  $$(2 + 2i)(4 + 2i) $$
- can we say that
  $$ n^{a+it} = (n^a)(n^{it}) $$

Comment: So are you asking how to calculate $(2+2i)(4+2i)$? I'm believe in you that you can do that yourself. Just open the parentheses and remember that $i^2 = -1$

Comment: Yes, you can multiply those two complex numbers, and simplify using $i^2=-1$. Your second statement is correct also.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the question about the "additional sign"

Comment: It's not really about computing $ (2+2i)(4+2i) $

Comment: @Peter, it’s a typo. He meant addition sign, i.e. “+”

Comment: That's quite simple but raising a number to a complex power s=a+it like in that famous Riemann zeta function

Comment: Is the question about the meaning of , for example "$-4-5i$" ? Is it "why are real part and imaginary part added" ?

Comment: Is the complex power to be split to the base as we always did in Algebra for only real numbers

Comment: @Joe Isn't it "$e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$" ?

Comment: @Peter, I think that Enock Kabibi is intuitively think of complex numbers as “vectors” in the complex plane, and therefore isn’t sure which rules of algebra apply to them. Since you cannot simply multiply two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, he’s wondering if you can multiply two complex numbers using the ordinary rules of algebra that he’s familiar with.

Comment: @Peter, Ah, yes, thank you. I’ll delete my erroneous comment.

Comment: @EnockKabibi So yeah unfortunately the + symbol has 2 meanings here. One is just as purely a symbol between the real and imaginary parts, and one as actually an operation. The good thing is, it doesn’t matter which interpretation you think about in a+bi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original reason for the $x + iy$ notation probably dates from a day of less formal and more intuitive notation.

A more contemporary reason is to define the complex numbers formally as ordered pairs $(x, y)$ but then observe that the subset $(x, 0)$ is isomorphic to the real numbers.  We now redefine the reals to be this subset and use just $x$ as a shorthand for $(x,0)$.  Next we define $i$ to be $(0,1)$.  We then find that $(x,y) = x(1,0) + y(0,1) = x +iy$.  So, $x + iy$ is just a convenient and familiar way to write $(x,y)$.

Similar steps happen when the integers are defined from the natural numbers, the rational numbers from the integers, and the reals from the rationals.  Strictly speaking the complex number $1$ is not the same as the real number $1$ and that is not the same as the rational $1$, the integer $1$, or the natural number $1$.  Each time we extend, we redefine the old smaller system as a subset of the new isomorphic to it.  Most of the time this is not confusing and makes life and notation simpler.  Occasionally, you need to remember this.

Comment: A wonderful book to read on the origin of the complex numbers is “Number: the language of science” by Tobias Dantzig.

Comment: Thank you badjohn

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about the the structure of the complex number field, why it has to be a plain other than a line

Comment: "Plane" not "plain".  That deserves a new question.  The representation on paper is for human convenience and not an intrinsic property.  It takes two real numbers to fully specify a complex number so they are 2 dimensional from a real point of view.  An alien who natively thinks in complex numbers might see it as 1 dimensional.